# In 'noun of noun that ... ', Which noun does relative clause modify?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

The sentence:

> features of the program needed

How should I understand it?

is it, **needed** modifying **the program**:

> features of **the program needed**

or, **needed** modifying **features of the program**:

> **features of the program** needed

Does It has to depend on context? If so, won't it often make ambiguity? when I read and saw the phrases, I always had to try to figure them. It bothers me a lot because often both ways seem to work.

How do you understand it and how should I express it unambiguous?

Comment: "features of the program needed" is not a sentence. It is not even a clause. There is not enough context here to evaluate the grammar. Please give at least a full sentence, and prferably several sentences or a parageaph to make this answerable.

Comment: It appears to be  just a noun phrase, typically used as a heading in some text. "Needed" is a past-participial clause modifying the NP "features of the program". Semantically, it is the equivalent of the relative clause in "features of the program that are needed".

Comment: What if you want to express this, like "features of **the program that is needed**"? How would you do?

Comment: If the relative clause "that is needed" is referring to the singular NP "the program", then it's fine as you've written it.